# Not able to set environment variables in JBPM as its throwing IOException

Tags: java, jbpm

I am facing this issue in jbpm while using tomcat7.

```
2013-06-10 14:58:29,628 (TaskProcessServlet.java:56) ERROR com.sample.processserver.TaskProcessServlet - cannot open disk journal
java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.read(FileDispatcher.java:28)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:198)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:171)
```

at the time of executing:

```
env.set( EnvironmentName.TRANSACTION_MANAGER, TransactionManagerServices.getTransactionManager());
```

Regards,
Vinay

Comment: It's evident that the error is somewhere else and not in the line you've pointed.

Comment: i am using mysql database.my 
persistent.xml file:
 <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.BTMTransactionManagerLookup"/>

And got this error:
ERROR com.sample.processserver.TaskProcessServlet - [PersistenceUnit: org.jbpm.persistence.jpa] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain BTM transaction manager instance


At the line of  :
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "org.jbpm.persistence.jpa" );

Answer (score 0):

Please reer link below: refer Nov 17, 2011" post

https://community.jboss.org/thread/174712?_sscc=t

It seems some process is locking the TaskProcessServlet.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I refereed this link but I am not getting fruitful answer.
Error : 
2013-06-10 15:45:27,412 (TaskProcessServlet.java:56) ERROR com.sample.processserver.TaskProcessServlet - [PersistenceUnit: org.jbpm.persistence.jpa] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain BTM transaction manager instance

In tomcat i done some setting Which is mentioned in : http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BTM/Tomcat

Comment: This exception means that you already have a bitronix instance still running (it's using a file to get a lock on). This could be the result of a previous execution that didn't shut down correctly. For example, if I run the same example multiple times in Eclipse and they each try to instantiate the bitronix transaction manager. Simply closing other running Java processes in Eclipse typically fixes this.

Comment: Thanks Harish for your reply,
Actually I close all the application. Even though I restart my PC.
but still same error :(